# Make Event handler in menu strip

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm posting here on SOF because I'm getting frustrated in C# WPF. :(
I don't know how to make an event handler in menustrip of WPF.
I know in ordinary win form and in VB.NET and in Buttons of WPF, JUST BY double clicking the controls (UI) I will be directed instantly in auto generated event handler.

In a menu strip of C#, when I assigned both Name and Click (click="button2Click") and then double click the menu tool or whatever you call that, I am being directed to the event handler of the HEADER of menustriptool.

Under "FILE" is "exit" menu. When I assigned click and name in that "exit" and then double click it, the focus will be in the "FILE".

XAML code:

```
<MenuItem Header="_FILE" >
        <MenuItem Header="_Open | View">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="Picture/open.png" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
            <MenuItem Header="_Connection String">
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Click="exitMenu_click">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="Picture/close1.png" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: done, I don't know why do I have to post my codes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add command in MenuItem and write handler for it. Simple.

```
<MenuItem Header="_FILE" >
    <MenuItem Header="_Open | View" Command=OpenCommand>
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="Picture/open.png" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
        <MenuItem Header="_Connection String">
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
```